# Hiding stack traces for custom exceptions on the logs using Google Endpoints in the Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing an application using Google Endpoints, and I created various custom exceptions which will be thrown when the user performs some unauthorised calls.
However I am getting a lot of log messages from "/_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages" as well as the whole stack trace in the method, is there a way to hide this in the App Engine Console logs?

Comment: Depending on what kind of exception you receive you could simply catch them in your endpoint and just log them without the stack trace. If you get this kind of exception for deserialization you'd have to adjust your class annotation until it fits (see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations) or use custom transformers.